# How to create a component that is a child of another component?

Tags: unity

I have several objects in my game that all have an `customEvent` component. I have three different types of `customEvent`, `customEventA, customEventB, customEventC`. At some point, I want to enable this `customEvent` component, but I don't know if its type `A, B, or C`.

What I want to do is just reference `GetComponent<customEvent>().enabled = true` and then it will automatically enable whatever type is actually attached to the GameObject.

What I am trying to do is similar to how `Collider` component works. You can have a `BoxCollider, SphereCollider, PolyCollider, etc.` and can refernce it by saying `GetComponent<Collider>()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `GetComponent<customEvent>()` already does exactly what you describe when I test it, returning an instance of whichever derived type happens to be attached to this object. Are you observing something different in practice? If so, please show your exact code for each type, so we can reproduce the problem. (Also, don't forget to name your types in `PascalCase` for consistency with the API, not `camelCase` like local variables)

Comment: Do events A,B and C extend from the base customEvent class? If so, GetComponent<CustomEvent>() will work as you'd expect.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 No, it does not extend from the base customEvent class, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how you have your scripts, but each event A, B and C needs to extend from a common base class.

Assuming your CustomEvent class looks like this

```
 //base class
public class CustomEvent : MonoBehaviour
{
   //whatever you have in here
}
```

You would make your A, B and C events inherit from this class

```
//extends base
public class CustomEventA : CustomEvent
{
   //whatever you have in here
}
```

Then when you call GetComponent<*CustomEvent*>() it doesn't matter which it is (A, B or C) as they all extend the same base class.

You can also use interfaces for this (with the caveat that they require extra checks if you are using GetComponent to retrieve the interface), but without knowing more I can't recommend an option.

You have to be careful that you don't try to call a function that doesn't exist, keep all functionality common to each CustomEvent A,B,C etc in the CustomEvent Base Class and they will inherit it from the Base Class.

For example if CustomEventA has a function named OnEventTrigger() but CustomEventB doesn't you will run into problems, if you are treating an object as a base class, it will only have access to the methods in the base class unless you cast it specifically to whatever type it is.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can mark the base class `abstract` if only the A/B/C derived variants are meant to be attached to game objects. Methods that the derived types need to `override` can be marked `virtual` or `abstract` on the base class to enable this.